# binary '==' : no operator found error for vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, stdvector

When I compile my C++ program in VS 2017 I get a compile error saying: binary'==':no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type `std::vector<int, std::allocator_Ty>`
(or there is no acceptable conversion). 
It is my first time working with 2 dimensional vectors, I am not sure about exactly if this could have been part of the cause. My code is below. Can anybody help find why this is happening?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> feeds;

void foo()
{
    find(feeds.begin(), feeds.end(), feeds[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: I edited the error statement, I had originally put brackets but that made part of the error message disappear, I have put the full error message back up.

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: @rsjaffe this one `feeds.erase(find(feeds.begin(), feeds.end(), feeds[l][k]));`   live: https://godbolt.org/g/VcV9Js    trying to find a `int` vector of vectors so comparison fails as comparing an `int` against a `vector` does not make sense.

Comment: That I do not know, because VS pointed me the the xutility, which I have a hard time understanding how to interpret. That is why I posted the question: to get some help in finding where the error is.

Comment: Format error messages as code.

Comment: wait... so what's the error?

Comment: `feeds[l][k]` is an integer. You cannot `find` an integer in a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to compare an int to a vector.

The line `feeds.erase(find(feeds.begin(), feeds.end(), feeds[l][k]));`, has two vector iterators (`feeds.begin()` and `feeds.end()`) but `feeds[l][k]` refers to a specific vector position rather than a vector. `feeds[l]` refers to the vectors, and should be used instead.

But why do you need `find` when you already know which vector to erase (`feeds[l]`). I suggest you check your logic and go from there.